# Issue getting txt file from folder not in the debug

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm working on a Monogame game with a group of classmates and we ran into a problem. We're trying to load in a .txt file that is placed in the folder below our solution file which is located here in monogame:

D:\Profiles\aa\Source\Repos\s2t3\Game\Game

The folder's file path itself is:
D:\Profiles\aa\Source\Repos\s2t3\Game\Game\AttackPattern\ratAttackOne.txt

But, Monogame starts from this folder:

D:\Profiles\aa\Source\Repos\s2t3\Game\Game\bin\Windows\x86\Debug\

How would we be able to write the file name to read in the txt file so it goes up into game, and then into Attack Pattern?

Comment: I don't think you want to go up.  I think you want to start at the root and go down.

Comment: Can you share your code? And also explain about the issue you're facing?

Comment: Set the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the file to `Copy If Newer`

Comment: We've tried: ../../../../AttackPatterns/ratOneAttack.txt

static String fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileLocation);

Comment: And if we need to start at the root, how would we go about going down from it?

Comment: Add the file to your project and in the properties window set it to copy to the output directory. This way a copy of it ends up next to your .exe

Answer (score 0):

You can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly to get your debug EXE path, and traverse it back to bin with a simple substring search:

```
string debugPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string basePath =
    debugPath.Substring(0,debugPath.IndexOf("\\bin\\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(basePath, "AttackPattern", "ratAttack.txt"));
```

Hope this helps. I suspect you know how to load a file.

Answer (score 0):

Just use StreamReader to read your txt file, then you can use the path ...\Game\Game\ or whatever you want in your Project's folder, not in debug folder.

```
            try
            {
                //Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("HighScore.txt");
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(
                    yourPathToTheTxtFileGoesHere));//for example, \AttackPattern\test.txt

                //do what you want to do with your txt file here

                streamReader.Close();

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {

            }
```